# Python: xpath find the that contains the exact word only

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I want to get the Total Assets data but return all data that contains Total Assets. **How can I get the data for Total Assets ONLY**?

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page_inv_n = requests.get('http://quotes.wsj.com/MY/XKLS/HEIM/financials/annual/balance-sheet')
inv_n = html.fromstring(page_inv_n.content)
Assets = inv_n.xpath(''//td[contains(.,"Total Assets")]/following-sibling::td/text()')[0]
```

The output that correct is `813,655.0` instead of `0.50%` which is from Cash & ST Investments / Total Assets that also contains Total Assets also.

Please advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can match node by exact text content as below:

```
//td[text()="Total Assets"]/following-sibling::td/text()
```

or

```
//td[.="Total Assets"]/following-sibling::td/text()
```

in this case both should work in the same way